# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')

Tags: reactjs

**Issue details**

Screen is blank and error message is here:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')

**Issue Screenshot**

[image]

Am i missing anything?

**App.js**

```
import { Routes, BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

import LoginComponent from './LoginComponent';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" >
                        <LoginComponent/>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Login Component**

```
import { React } from 'react';

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-4 ">
                Login Html
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default LoginComponent;
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the following in Login.js

```
import { React } from 'react';
```

to

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Also change

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<LoginComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

instead of

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" >
     <LoginComponent/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: `element={<LoginComponent />} />` is fine and is what's shown/recommended upfront in the react-router v6 docs so this isn't a required change.